# Unable to cast ComboBoxItem to String or Int

Tags: c#, string, combobox, casting, type-conversion

I have small form with one dropbox, one textBox, two ComboBoxes and one list(for selection).

Code has no errors, but when I attempt to save the form and store data in database I get this:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.'

```
+       $exception  {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(Object value)
```

Here is the code:

```
Db_Helper.InsertData(new 
Data((Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem)),
     (Convert.ToString(SelectedProductName.Text.Trim())),
     (Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)),
     //error below
     (Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)),
     (Convert.ToString(ComboBox2.SelectedItem))));
```

I believe the problem is with `ComboBox1` Conversion.

Comment: Why downvote here?

Comment: To answer your question i voted down because there was no attempt to actually isolate the problem and reduce the degrees of freedom, the title doesn't match the description of the problem and has nothing to do with a database from the code supplied, and who even knows what DB_Helper does but is most likely completely independent of what the problem is. Just saying you could have put a lot more effort in

Answer (score 0):

You do your conversion wrongly. `'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBoxItem'` is a usual CLR `Object` as everything in the `.NET`. Each object ships overloadable `.ToString()` method, so whenever you want default string representations of whatever object or it's subclass, you rather call `myObject.ToString()`.

Same applies to the `ToInt32(...)`. Proceed on `.int.Parse/TryParse` to get strongly typed integer from the string. When you'll do this, you'll get a clearer error at least.

Comment: I tried: "(int.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()))"  now I get error that says "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: @positiveperspective which means that you have to place debug breakpoint at that moment and accurately examine what is there in the `SelectedItem/SelectedValue` property.

Comment: I am sure there are numbers only

Comment: @positiveperspective if such, it would parse them errorlessly. But it didn't. I'll let you to deduce conclusion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedItem` property gives you the `ComboBoxItem`. What you want is only the value, so use the `SelectedValue` property instead.

You wanted to convert the value to an integer, but the `Convert.ToInt32()` takes a string while the `SelectedValue` property is an `object`. You can use the `.ToString()` on it to convert it to string.

Also don't convert string values (like `SelectedProductName.Text`) to string, that's redundant.

```
Db_Helper.InsertData(new 
Data(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(),
     SelectedProductName.Text.Trim(),
     Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text),
     Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()),
     ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

**EDIT** You need to bind your `ComboBox`es and `ListBox` properly using the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` properties. The first one will display the items' text, and the second one will store the items' ID. Then you can get the ID using the `SelectedValue` property in the code above.

Here is an example of how to bind the `ComboBox` to a list of vegetables sorted alphabetically:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, string>{
           {100, "Eggplant"},
           {102, "Onion"},
           {300, "Potato"},
           {105, "Tomato"},
           {200, "Zuccini"}
};
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = data;
ComboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
ComboBox1.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
```

Your `ComboBox1` in XAML must have no items. As you can see, I bound the `DisplayMemberPath` to the `Value` of the `Dictionary` and the `SelectedValuePath` to the `Key`. You can use any values you want for IDs and they don't have to be sequential like the index. This way, if you add a new item in the future, the IDs of the current items will not change. Let say you want to add Garlic in the alphabetical order:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int,string>{
           {100, "Eggplant"},
           {302, "Garlic"},
           {102, "Onion"},
           {300, "Potato"},
           {105, "Tomato"},
           {200, "Zuccini"}
};
```

If you use `int` for the `Key`, you don't need to convert it like you did in your code, you can simply use a direct cast. Similarly, for `listBox1` and `ComboBox2` you can use `string` for the `Key` if you like and you won't need conversion:

```
Db_Helper.InsertData(new 
Data((string)listBox1.SelectedValue,
     SelectedProductName.Text.Trim(),
     Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text),
     (int)ComboBox1.SelectedValue),
     (string)ComboBox2.SelectedValue);
```

If you prefer to keep the items in XAML instead of code-behind, there is no equivalent to the `SelectedValuePath` property, but you can simulate it using the `Tag` property like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Eggplant" Tag="100" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Onion" Tag="102" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Potato" Tag="300" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Tomato" Tag="105" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Zuccini" Tag="200" />
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: but it gives me same error when I try to save the form

Comment: That's probably because of the first line `listBox1.SelectedItem`. Same problem and same fix, change it to `listBox1.SelectedValue`.

Comment: I changed that as well but I get the same error. listBox1 is not a comboBox but a list of records.

Comment: You also have issues with the conversions. See my updated answer for a complete code. Also make sure that those values your are trying to convert with `Convert.ToInt32()` are actually numbers.

Comment: What I have is the xaml code where I specify comboBox items.

Comment: Do I need to create class to store Dropbox values?

Comment: I get error that says: ComboBox does not contain definition for DataSource(the same for DisplayMember and ValueMember).

Comment: That's because you use WPF not WinForms. I didn't notice that until now. I updated my answer, check it now.

Comment: It's UWP actually

Answer (score 0):

I think your casting syntax is wrong to convert into string we use toString method at the end of the statement like below.

```
ComboBox2.SelectedItem.toString();
```

**I Hope This Will Help You**

Comment: tried that but does not change anything. error persists.

Comment: Then instead of SelectedItem Use Text Property of ComboBox like `ComboBox2.Text` Try This

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of SelectedItem use Text property of combobox like below

```
ComboBox2.Text
```

and you don't have to convert it into string it always returns string

**I Hope This Will Help You**

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution myself. 
The error was indeed at this line:

```
(Convert.ToInt32(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)),
```

I had to modify it a bit like this:

```
(int.Parse(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString())),
```

I was getting errors until I changed

> SelectedItem

to

> SelectedIndex

. Program works well now and I am able to pull selected data from ComboBox.

Comment: That means your `ComboBox` is set-up incorrectly. You cannot depend on the index, because it can change if you sort the items differently. When you bind the data to your `ComboBox`, you need to bind both the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties. The first one will display the text items, and the second one will store the IDs of those items. Then you should get the ID using the `SelectedValue` property like in my answer.

Comment: But this combo box is not bonded with any data. It has fixed selection of numbers from 1 to 5.

Comment: Still the same problem. What if you change the items in the future? Let's say you add an item between the second and third items, the index of the last three items will change, and all the data that you will have saved will point to the wrong items.

Comment: I don't know how to resolve the problem then as your solution gives me error. Any idea? I'm sure the error occurs on the comboBox mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain how to achieve what you wrote in your first comment?

Comment: Thanks. I will look through it shortly and get back to you.